# When in resolution phase to apply Hyde park's effect

Tags: vampire-the-masquerade-vendetta

Hyde Park, a location card, reads:

> Before applying any other effect, the Power of the Deployed card (or cards) here with the highest printed Power value becomes 0.

While this seems fairly clear, it actually is unclear when "applying effects" happens during the resolution stage. The resolution stage is split on:

- Withdraw
- Revelation
- Preparation
- Conflict
- Aftermath

All of these may have cards applying effects, and it doesn't actually make sense to resolve Hyde Park *before* Withdraw because then you might just reduce a card to 0 that ends up not even being there. Similarly, if Hyde Park only applies during Conflict, cards may have entered or left the location by then. So, when should I apply Hyde Park?

Cards to consider:

Ventrue's Mass Manipulation:

> During the Withdraw Step at this Location, each Rival must either Withdraw or let you Steal 2 blood from them to Stay.

Malkavian's Malkav's Bane:

> Immediately after Revelation, draw the top card from your Clan deck and play it at this Location. At the end of the [...]

So, do I apply Hyde park before or after Malkav's Bane card has been played in the Location? (Because this may change which cards are affected).

One option is to apply Hyde park's effect *before* any Preparation card effects, but this isn't exactly spelled out that it should be like that anywhere. And technically is after some effects have been resolved, so not 100% in line with the text in the card either. The other option would be *immediately after revelation* but *before* any cards that happen *immediately after revelation* too.

When should I apply Hyde park's effect?